# How many ways there are to paint the strip of n cells with 3 colors

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways there are to paint the strip of `N` cells, using `R` red cells, `B` blue cells, `G` green cells if `R+G+B=N`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After painting the $N$ cells they can be ordered. This originally in $N!$ ways.

Exactly $R!G!B!$ orders produce the same colourpattern. So there are $$\frac{N!}{R!G!B!}$$ different patterns.

Comment: Multinomial coefficient? Ok, thx