# Count the number of ways of painting the strip with 3 colors

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways there are to paint the strip of N cells, using NOT LESS than A yellow cells, B red cells, C blue cells? I found similar question, but my case is different
[How many ways there are to paint the strip of n cells with 3 colors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740871/how-many-ways-there-are-to-paint-the-strip-of-n-cells-with-3-colors)

Comment: How is this question different?

Comment: The condition $A+B+C=N$ means that if we use not less than $\dots$, we must use **exactly** $A$ yellow, $B$ red, $C$ blue.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is as stated (exactly $A$ yellow, $B$ red, $C$ blue), it is just a multinomial coefficient. Consider it like this: Number the yellow strips $1$ to $A$, the red ones $1$ to $B$, and the blue ones $1$ to $C$. Then the problem is how to paint the strip with $N$ different color swatches, which can be done in $N!$ ways. But this overcounts by the reorderings of the swatches of each color ("turn off their numbers"), so you have to divide by $A! \, B! \, C!$, in all:
$$
\frac{(A + B + C)!}{A! \, B! \, C!} = \binom{A + B + C}{A, B, C}
$$

Comment: No, i've made mistake in statement and have already correct it. Sorry

Comment: I'm afraid that any solution will just be summing over multinomial coefficients for all possible values of the number of cells of each color. Such sums over parts of the ranges don't have closed forms.